# Python - setting the attribute of an object

Tags: python, class, attributes

I am asked to add an attribute to the program. This attribute is to display a change of Zara's new salary of 3000.

I am asked to add it as a `setattr(obj,name,value)` function to set Zara a new salary.

This is my code:

```
__author__ = 'SWA14096171'

class Employee:

    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.empCount +=1

    def displayCount (self):
        print('total employee %d') % Employee.empCount

    def displayEmployee (self) :
        print (' Name : ', self.name, ', Salary: ', self.salary)

emp1 = Employee('Zara', 2000)

emp2 = Employee (' Manni', 5000)
emp1.displayEmployee()
emp2.displayEmployee()
print ('Total Employee %d' % Employee.empCount)
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. The second bit of code appears to be an attempt to display all the class attributes. What does this have to do with changing the salary of one of the instances?

Comment: The last bit was me attempting to do this, I have a power point to work off but it doesn't explain it very well. Hence why im on SO. Could you help at all?

Comment: No, I don't understand how that is an attempt to do anything at all to do with changing Zara's salary to 3000. Where is the bit where you try to do that?

Comment: please give us a minimum example, get rid of all the boilerplate.

Comment: I am looking to add an attribute of Zara's salary changing from 2000 to 3000 and displaying it.

Comment: Yes that's what you said. **Show the code** for where you have tried to change Zara's salary. Hint: that code should contain the value 3000.

Comment: print ( '\nEmployee Attributes...')
for attrib in dir( Employee ):
    if attrib[0] != '_' :
        print ( attrib , ':' , getattr( Employee , attrib ) )

this came off the powerpoint I have, I don't actually understand it just trying to get a better grip of this change

Comment: I am asked to add it as a setattr(obj,name,value) function to set Zara a new salary.

Comment: OK, so why don't you do that then? That is a clear instruction, which you should have mentioned at the start, and has nothing at all to do with this "powerpoint" you keep referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't fret. It is as easy as it gets:

```
emp1.salary = 3000
```

If you want to change a value of an attribute, just assign a new value to it. Then you can print it as you wish.

```
print emp1.salary    #just salary
print "%s's salary is %d" % (emp1.name, emp1.salary)  #salary and name
emp1.displayEmployee()   # using your method
```

Hope that helps!